# Smalltalk question about genetic distance

Tags: smalltalk

In my homework i received a question on how to code generic distance in smalltalk.

in Smalltalk a genetic distance between classes (new thing) is the amount of minimal father steps or son steps that you need to pass in the tree of inheritance if you start at one class until you reach the second class.

for example: the genetic distance between SmallInteger to Number is 2 and the distance between Point and TranslucentColor is 3. you need to code what is needed in order for the message geneticDistance will be sent to the class with the class argument and will return the genetic distance between the two classes.

in case the receiver of the message or argument or both is not a type of a class or meta class so for classes like these we will calculate the genetic distance from the class of the object. sending each of the following messages will return 2:

SmallInteger geneticDistance: Number 3 geneticDistance: Number Number geneticDistance:3

and the following message will return 4:

4.5 geneticDistance:3

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because no question is being asked

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Comment: the question is how could you code such a thing?

Comment: "you need to code what is needed in order for the message geneticDistance will be sent to the class with the class argument and will return the genetic distance between the two classes."

Comment: Please read [how do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of solving the problem for you, let me point out some tips to structure your solution:

1. Since the definition of `genericDistance:` is a sum a two things, you can easily apply the conquer and divide strategy.
2. Since the argument can be of two kinds, instance or class/metaclass, you can first solve it when the argument is a `Class` or `Metaclass` and then defer to this solution when the argument is not either of these. Here you should also use the fact that `genericDistance:` is symmetric.
3. Once you have the solution for classes (1 above), you should try to solve it when the argument is a `Metaclass`, always deferring all calculations to what you already have for classes (there is a tricky part here though, but let's ignore it for now).
4. Before attempting any implementation, write down a test with the simplest example you can think of. Make it pass and then repeat.

**--Addendum--**

Test

```
GenericDistanceTest >> test0
  self assert: (Number genericDistance: Number) equals: 0
```

Solution:

```
Class >> genericDistance: aClass
     aClass == self ifTrue: [^0].
```

Test

```
GenericDistanceTest >> test1
  self assert: (Integer genericDistance: SmallInteger) equals: 1
```

Solution:

```
Class >> genericDistance: aClass
     aClass == self ifTrue: [^0].
     aClass superclass == self ifTrue: [^1]
```

Test

```
GenericDistanceTest >> test2
  self assert: (Number genericDistance: SmallInteger) equals: 1
```

Solution:

```
Class >> genericDistance: aClass
     aClass == self ifTrue: [^0].
     aClass superclass == self ifTrue: [^1].
     (aClass inheritsFrom: self)
        ifTrue: [^(self genericDistance: aClass superclass) + 1]
```

... keep going.

Comment: this homework is in a course that im not ever going to use i just need to pass this assignment

Comment: People are trying to help you with your homework - please don't get rude, Netef. You haven't shown any attempt to work this out yourself, which is usually a prerequisite for asking questions.

Comment: Well. You need to think. The first test: `self assert: (Number genericDistance: Number) equals: 0`. Can you make this test pass? Second `self assert: (SmallInteger genericDistance: Integer) equals: 1`. Solve these and you will be involved with the problem.

Comment: why rude? i just said that i dont really need to know this... i just need the answer

Comment: @NetefNisani If you read carefully the hints I proposed, you will train some abilities that you will use in the future, no matter what you end up doing: structuring a problem, dividing it into parts, solving first the easy bits, composing solutions, checking their validity and scope, etc. Your brain is you best tool, get used to train it.

Comment: i work in the industry for years i know the thing your saying and i agree with it. i just dont know how to implement in in smalltalk that is the whole situation

Comment: Then your question it too ambitious. Asking good questions is also something you need to train. Let me write an addendum to my answer for you to get started.

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea is to find the distance to the root (Object) by following superclasses, then eliminate the shared classes, then sum the sizes of the remaining lists.

Comment: hi i understand that this is the concept but i dont know how to code it in smalltalk can you give me a lead?